# How to implement video chat in web application (mvc/asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developed application in .net and i have to implement video chat in my application which is only intact with only application users. Please help me or provide any API for video chat implementation.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

This links from Google search.

[Audio/Video/Text chat in ASP.Net app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624442/audio-video-text-chat-in-asp-net-app)

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/13766/mvc-3-razor-video-chat

[Real Time Video Chatting + Recording solution in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373558/real-time-video-chatting-recording-solution-in-asp-net-mvc)

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1491/chat-application-with-signalr-and-aspnet-mvc-4

Please more details search on Google. I think Google is a best for that.